# me salen ErrorException in Builder.php line 1231: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, composer

hola tengo un problema resulta que clone un projecto de github y le puse el .env
mi duda es me sale un error el cual tiene el siguiente codigo

3/3
ErrorException in Builder.php line 1231:
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\gestion-incidencias-master\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\gestion-incidencias-master\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php)
in Builder.php line 1231
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), '1') in compiled.php line 15637
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\xampp\htdocs\gestion-incidencias-master\storage\framework\views/d977e7cda5c23b300782e7016c60a08ebe440c24.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'my_incidents' => array(), 'pending_incidents' => array(), 'incidents_by_me' => array())) in compiled.php line 15672
at CompilerEngine->get('C:\xampp\htdocs\gestion-incidencias-master\resources\views/home.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'my_incidents' => array(), 'pending_incidents' => array(), 'incidents_by_me' => array())) in compiled.php line 15504
at View->getContents() in compiled.php line 15492
at View->renderContents() in compiled.php line 15476
at View->render() in compiled.php line 16749
at Response->setContent(object(View)) in compiled.php line 16236
at Response->__construct(object(View)) in compiled.php line 8499
at Router->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(View)) in compiled.php line 8345
at Router->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 10167
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 10059
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in Authenticate.php line 43
at Authenticate->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 10059
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 3312
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 10059
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 13739
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 10059
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 12145
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 10059
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 13485
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 10059
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 13422
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 10059
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 10044
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 8346
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8337
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 8328
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2575
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 3374
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 10059
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 10044
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in compiled.php line 2519
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2503
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
at require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\gestion-incidencias-master\public\index.php') in server.php line 21
2/3
ErrorException in Builder.php line 1231:
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\gestion-incidencias-master\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php)

no se  A QUE SE DEBA si mis conexiones estan bien enturadas y no le modifique nada

Comment: El mensaje de error es claro: estás intentando usar `count()` en un objeto que no es contable, o sea, debe ser un array o un objeto que implemente la interfaz `Countable`. Eso suele ocurrir cuando intentas usar `count()` con una variable simple por ejemplo. De todos modos, pulsa en [edti] y en vez de capturas de pantalla pon el texto del código, pues es más fácil de verificar.

Comment: ya puse el error del codigo